# Selecting all cells not containing a number in SQL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a field containing some  values. In edit mode, when I click on any one of these  values it gets replaced by 1.#QNAN in the cell.

I would like to query the table for all cells containing 1.#QNAN values. When I try to query for Null values (SELECT FROM .... WHERE .... IS NULL) no rows get selected. So Im assuming SQL doesn't recognize that 1.#QNAN are in fact null values.

How do I get the select by attributes dialog box to select all cells not containing a number?

Comment: NaN (Not a number) is a complex type and is handled differently between databases, please indicate the *exact* storage for these features. You might not be able to select 1.#QNAN due to database/SQL limitations - perhaps instead select all the 'good' values and then invert selection.

Comment: Im not sure what is they exact storage. They are of data type double and generated from a relate with a publicly available shapefile. Please indicate to me how I can use SQL to select values which ARE a number. I would consider this a valid answer.

Comment: Try IS NOT NULL to select any valid value (I know NaN is neither null nor not null) then switch selection... to select unmatched records in a join I select primary_key = related.primary_key then switch, that might work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> NaN (Not a number) is a complex type and is handled differently
>   between databases, please indicate the exact storage for these
>   features. You might not be able to select 1.#QNAN due to database/SQL
>   limitations - perhaps instead select all the 'good' values and then
>   invert selection.

and

> Try IS NOT NULL to select any valid value (I know NaN is neither null
>   nor not null) then switch selection... to select unmatched records in
>   a join I select primary_key = related.primary_key then switch, that
>   might work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE str(COLUMN) = ' nan'
```

As '1.#QNAN' should appear as ' nan' when converted to a string.

Comment: Asterisk is not a valid wildcard in SQL.

Comment: My mistake, I was using this SQL query in MS Access where asterisks are valid. I've updated the answer so it works for more general cases.